# Create url for a image in an angularjs project?

Tags: angularjs

In my website I'm using a service that needs an url to load an image.

How can I create an URL from an image that only exists in the filesystem of the project?

**EDIT**

I need the url for $og_image_url of Socialshare service.

Comment: by using `relative path`?

Answer (score 1):

An angular have separate directive called ng-src

```
<img ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}" alt="Description" />
```

or

```
<img ng-src="img/image.png" alt="Description" />
```

Comment: But i don't want to use it in html. I need the url in controller.

Comment: @kilkus You can declare the $scope variable for image url param. Ex $scope.serverUrl use to ng-src={{serverUrl}}

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.image="http://helpacoder.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/angular.jpeg";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h1>Angular</h1>
    <img ng-src="{{image}}">
  <h4>Or</h4>
  <div ng-init="images='http://helpacoder.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/angular.jpeg'">
  <p>Another Way </p>
    <img ng-src="{{images}}"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Two way to display the image in angular js.